# Error message as :Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<1>. Actual:<0>

Tags: c#

I am getting the error as:

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<1>. Actual:<0>

and the related code is here below;
can anyone tell me what is the problem and how can I fix this?

```
[TestMethod]
[TestProperty("TestCaseId", "637683")]
public void DiscoveryFunctionalTests_BucketedPivotTests_TVShowOnly_ItemsPerRowBasicScenario_NoError()
{
    var pivotConstraints = new List<string> { "ShowType|TVShow" };
    var items = this.clientContext.DiscoveryClient.GetBucketedPivotItems(pivotConstraints, groups: discoveryGroups, itemsPerRow: 1).ToList();

    Assert.IsNotNull(items.FirstOrDefault(), "No pivot items were returned");
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        //error is here  Assert.AreEqual(1, item.Items.Count());
        Assert.IsTrue(
            item.Items.All(
                queryItem =>
                    ((queryItem.ItemType == QueryItemType.Series) ||
                    ((queryItem.ItemType == QueryItemType.Program) && (this.clientContext.DiscoveryClient.GetProgramById(queryItem.Id).ShowType == ShowType.TVShow)))));
    }
}
```

Comment: The code under test has been changed so that it no longer produces the expected output. Go to the object under test and see what has been changed since it worked last.

Comment: If a test fails, either the code is wrong or the test is wrong. You need to fix at the right place so that the code is right and the test is making sense